# Is It Possible To Send Special Payload From EventBridge Schedule To The Target (Lambda) If The Schedule Is Retried

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

New to AWS so please bare that in mind.

I have an EventBridge schedule that targets a lambda function.
Now what I want to achieve is, if the EventBridge schedule is retried, send a special payload to the target (lambda function) and use that payload inside the target.

So basically I want to know inside the target (lambda) that the current execution is a retry.

Is there a way to know inside the target (lambda) that it is currently operating on a retry attempt from an EventBridge schedule?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: No, there is no such way.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer.